# Win32_PhysicalMedia - get IDE SerialNumber

Tags: c#, .net

When getting the Serial Number from Win32_PhysicalMedia

```
SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia
```

Please let us know how do I identity it is related to the `HardDisk('IDE')`. But it is also returning the serial number of the USB stick.

I can get the serial number from the `Win32_DiskDrive`, due to the serial number mismatch we need to use it from `Win32_PhysicalMedia`.

Comment: I feel like info is missing from this post. What information do you need exactly? What exactly is the issue with the USB drives, you are getting the serial for the USB drives and do not want them?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a persistent bug in the 'Win32_PhysicalMedia' class, when querying it under elevated privileges. If you query it in a standard-Users context, the returned serial is the same as the one returned by 'Win32_DiskDrive'. As administrator there seems to happen some byte-douplet inversion.

The administrator gets:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object -Property SerialNumber
ABCDEF
Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMedia | Select-Object -Property SerialNumber
BADCFE
```

The user gets:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object -Property SerialNumber
ABCDEF
Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMedia | Select-Object -Property SerialNumber
ABCDEF
```

The bug exists since Vista, and Microsoft chose to ignore it. See here for more Information:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623282/win32-physicalmedia-returns-incorrect-serial-number-on-vista-or-higher-when-run-as-standard-user